# Recursively remove empty nodes from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'd like to remove empty elements from some html string. I know I could run something like:

```
$('p').each(function(index, item) {
    if($.trim($(item).text()) === "") {
        $(item).remove();
    }
});
```

The problem is that I want to remove all empty nodes - not only p. Also I want the script to consider p node in `<p><span></span></p>` as empty because it contains only empty elements. Do you have some simple implementation of something like that?

[EDIT]
I forgot to add: I can use jQuery but the html I want to traverse and edit is in a string - not the actual document. So how can I do this operation? I tried using `var html = $.parseHTML('<p><span></span></p>')` but after each loop I still get the same string...

Comment: To select all elements, $('*'), but be careful with that, it might be safer to have a list of elements that it makes sense to remove e.g. $('p,h1,h2') or something similar as you might not want to remove a <br/> or <hr/> tag. As for nested elements, I am not sure.

Comment: Refere this http://jsfiddle.net/LEKaL/6/

Comment: Should an element containing only tabs, newlines and other empty tags also be detected as empty? (e.g. `<p>\n<span></span>\n</p>`)

Comment: If some child tag is empty than yes, it should be treated as empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently I was looking for a solution to the same problem. A recursive function was the answer.

```
function removeEmptyTagsRecursively($el) {
    if ($el.children().length) {

        $el.children().each(function(i, val) {
            removeEmptyTagsRecursively($(val));
        });

        $el.children(':empty').remove();
    }
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/635utakr/9/

Comment: Excellent recursive function example :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tweek of [Paul's function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581685/recursively-remove-empty-nodes-from-html#32489835) for vanilla JS (requires [Element.matches() polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)):

```
function removeEmpty(parent) {
    // for each child
    [].forEach.call(parent.children, function(child) {
        // repeat operation
        removeEmpty(child);

        // remove if it matches selector
        if (child.matches(':empty')) {
            parent.removeChild(child);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
do {
    empty = $("*:empty");
    count = empty.length;
    empty.remove();
}
while ( count > 0 );
```

It's iterative rather than recursive, but should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Actually Your code is working Fine. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YN9vE/).

It's showing only, which having content inside. Then What you Want?

HTML

```
<p>hi 1</p>
<p></p>
<p><span>hi 2</span></p>
<p><span></span></p>
```

Script

```
$('p').each(function(index, item) {
    if($.trim($(item).text()) === "") {
        $(item).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: See my edit... Actualy I do not want to operate on html document but some custom string - this means that $(item).remove() doesn't exactly do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using below code:-

```
function removeEmptyTag(root) {
    var $root = $(root);
    $root.contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType === 1) {
        removeEmptyTag(this);
    }
    });

    if (!$root.is("area,base,col,command,embed,hr,img,input,keygen,link,meta,param,source,track,wbr") && !$root.html().trim().length) {
    $root.remove();
    }
}

removeEmptyTag("#divIdHere");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEKaL/6/)